# How to solve trouble with MDX error: "Two sets specified in the function have different dimensionality."?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx

```
WITH
SET TopCountry AS BOTTOMCOUNT( [Dimension Client].[Nazwa Firmy].MEMBERS, 3,      IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Fracht]), 0, [Measures].[Fracht]))
MEMBER [Order Count] AS (IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Facts Orders Count]), 0, [Measures].[Facts Orders Count]))

SELECT
[Order Count] ON COLUMNS,
TopCountry ON ROWS
FROM [N Wind PL2]
WHERE {
    ([Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[1]),
    ([Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[2]),
    ([Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[3]),
    ([Dimension Client].[Kraj].&[USA]),
    ([Dimension Client].[Kraj].&[Meksyk])
}
```

I have error, which I wrote in title and I searched it in google and solutions were not understandable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got the brackets and braces a bit mixed up on your where clause. Try:

```
WHERE
    (
        {
            [Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[1],
            [Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[2],
            [Time].[Hierarchy].[Order Year].&[1997].&[3]
        },
        {
            [Dimension Client].[Kraj].&[USA],
            [Dimension Client].[Kraj].&[Meksyk]
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

put hierarchy in one brace and dimension in one brace